# Prove that normality of operator is equivalent to being self adjoint if $P$ is idempotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be idempotent operator defined on $V$ and $\dim(V)<\infty$.

Prove that $PP^{*} = P^{*}P \iff P = P^{*}$

I was thinking about something like this

$$\langle PP^*x,y\rangle = \langle Px, Py\rangle = \langle x,PP^*y\rangle = \langle P^*x, P^*y\rangle$$

Hence,

$\langle Px, Py\rangle = \langle P^*x, P^*y\rangle$ but I don't know if it's equivalent to $P=P^*$?
Also where do we have to use this idempotency?

Comment: If $P$ is normal then it's orthogonally diagonalizable, and then idempotency would imply the eigenvalues are all either 0 or 1.

Comment: This is not proper MathJax usage: $$<PP^*x,y> = <Px, Py> = <x,PP^*y> = <P^*x, P^*y>$$I changed it to this: $$\langle PP^*x,y\rangle = \langle Px, Py\rangle = \langle x,PP^*y\rangle = \langle P^*x, P^*y\rangle$$ Also, when you write A\dim B or A\dim (B) then you see (respectively) $A\dim B$ or $A\dim(B)$ with $\dim$ _not_ italicized and with proper spacing, including more space to the right of $\dim$ in that first expression than in the second.  \dim is the right way to do that. $\qquad$

Comment: If there are some non-idempotent operators that are normal but not self-adjoint then you'll have to use the hypothesis of idempotence. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

You proved that $\|Px\|=\|P^*x\|$ if (and in fact only if) $P$ is normal; this will not imply that $P$ is self-adjoint without the extra assumption that $P=P^2$.

With this assumption in place, notice that $R(P)^{\perp}= N(P^*)=N(P)$. Moreover, if $x\in R(P)$, so $x=Py$, then $Px = P^2y = Py =x$. Also, if $x\in N(P)$, then of course $Px =0$. So $P$ is the (orthogonal) projection onto $R(P)$, and it's easy to show that a projection is self-adjoint:
$$
\langle x, Py \rangle = \langle Px + (1-P)x , Py \rangle = \langle Px, Py\rangle ,
$$
(since $(1-P)x\in N(P)$) and this equals $\langle Px, y\rangle$, by repeating these steps.

Comment: Sorry but in class we haven't defined what $R(P)$ or $N(P)$ is. I suppose there has to be easier proof, because our profesor only told us what is self-adjoint operator and normal operator with few features.

Comment: @janusz: $R(P)$ = range of $P$, $N(P)$ = null space (aka kernel)